# mergin 2 Sets to an aggregation Object

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a method that need to create `Map[Integer, Data]` based on 2 `Sets`. It is kind of merge for the parameters where the key in the map is the key of each tuple in the sets, and the value is `Data` object constructed with the tuples values.

```
def craete(included: Set[(Int, Set[Int])], excluded: Set[(Int, Set[Int])]) {
//create new Map[Integer, Data]...
}
```

and the dataObject class:

```
class Data(included: Seq[Integer], excluded: Seq[Integer]) {
}
```

Comment: Why are included and excluded sets and not maps? Are the "keys" assumed to be unique?

Comment: yes, I guess I can transform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class Data(included: Set[Int], excluded: Set[Int])

def create(included: Map[Int, Set[Int]], excluded: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): Map[Int, Data] = {
  val keys = included.keySet union excluded.keySet
  keys.iterator.map(id => id -> Data(
    included.getOrElse(id, Set.empty), 
    excluded.getOrElse(id, Set.empty))
  ).toMap
}
```

Note that there is no `Integer` in scala